# How can I use private helm repository with Spinnaker?

Tags: kubernetes, artifactory, kubernetes-helm, spinnaker

I want to use Artifactory as private Helm repository and deploy my app using helm chart to Kubernetes everytime a new version of helm chart gets uploaded to Artifactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. You can find more information about it [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Helm+Chart+Repositories)

The Helm charts repo is a [web server that serves files](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#the-chart-repository-structure), it could also be something like Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage bucket and then you can add an `index.yaml` file and then all your charts.  So you could also integrate that with Spinnaker.